# Can I help with the commuity wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Can I help with the commuity wiki? Should I?

I think what does X mean for Y questions would be a great addition, for philosophy.stackexchange

E.g.:

[What is "intuition" for Kant?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41579/what-is-intuition-for-kant)